# loading PHP into Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to output the query into a javascript object. I searched the internet for articles on how to get this done but I can't seem to understand.

The query is done in the php code below. My question is how do I output the results from a php variable into a javascript object? Can someone guide me as to how to get this done?

```
 <?php

$connect = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=bis user=bran6 password=cbrat") or die("Could not connect: ");
$result = pg_query($connect,"SELECT distinct thestartgeom FROM bike");
if (!$result)
{
echo "no results ";
}
$data[];
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{

 $data[] = $row['the_start'];

}

pg_close($connect);
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
      </style>
 var ar =<?php echo json_encode($data)?>;

  writeln(ar);
</script>
   </head>
   <body>
  </body>
 </html>
```

When I look at the console I receive a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

Comment: `ajax` my friend, `ajax`. It's all you need.

Comment: what is the the rendered code? (view source from browser)

Comment: It is the same as the code posted here.

Comment: @BrandonJ it cannot be the same, if it is, then  your page isn't preprocessed by php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some markups errors.

First, where is your `<body>` opening tag?

Second, you're running an `writeln` function wrongly, the correct way is to `document.writeln`

Also, your `<?php echo json_encode($data)?>` is returning something that javascript can't handle, so, the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` is being throw